# Name of the encoding format

Tags: encoding

I was recently dealing with some encoding that was using this type of encoding showed below. Does it have some name?

```
3006BEIJING
```

Meaning

```
30         =>   ID of the property
06         =>   length of the data
BEIJING    =>   the data
```

With the knowledge that Id and length is always represented with 2 characters, it can be easily read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a variation of TLV aka "Type Length Value".

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value :

> Within data communication protocols, TLV (type-length-value or tag-length-value) is an encoding scheme used for optional information element in a certain protocol.
>
> The type and length are fixed in size (typically 1-4 bytes), and the value field is of variable size. These fields are used as follows:
>
> **Type**
>       A binary code, often simply alphanumeric, which indicates the kind of field that this part of the message represents;
>
> **Length**
>       The size of the value field (typically in bytes);
>
> **Value**
>       Variable-sized series of bytes which contains data for this part of the message.